# Валидатор email не понимает кирилические домены

Tags: yii2, activerecord

```
    public function rules() {
    return [
           ...
           ['email', 'email'],
           ...]
```

Валидатор 'email' Yii2 не пропускает русские домены типа .рус, .рф
Говорит что введенный емайл не является email.
Как быть?

Comment: Напишите свой валидатор ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Отнаследуйте базовый валидатор, например, и переопределите метод с изменением части логики

Comment: хотелось бы это иметь "из коробки" :-)

Comment: Сейчас напишу вариант. Но знайте. что не всё есть из коробки. Потому что нельзя написать все варианты на все случаи жизни. Никогда не знаешь что именно **другим** разработчикам понадобится)) У нас в проекте оооооочень много переопределённых виджетов с дописанной под себя логикой

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-emailvalidator#$enableIDN-detail а это не про оно?

Comment: спасибо ребята за помощь! пойду осознаю....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из параметров **[валидатор email](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-emailvalidator)**  может принимать **[свойство "enableIDN"](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-emailvalidator#$enableIDN-detail)**. Оно даёт понять фреймворку, нужно ли учитывать IDN (многоязычные доменные имена). По умолчанию значение `false`.

**NOTICE:** Также нужно помнить, что для использования IDN-валидации вам нужно установить и включить в *PHP* расширение `intl` (php-extension-intl,  а также что в php.ini раскоментированны нужные строки), иначе будет выброшено исключение.

И ещё заметка: возможно (не могу сказать точно) валидацию придётся сделать серверную, а не клиентскую

Итог:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ...
        ['email', 'email', 'enableIDN' => true],
        ...
    ];
}
```